# Javascript regular expression that replaces html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regular expression in javascript to replace all occurances of

```
</tr><tr>
```

with

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

Also, there can be whitespace between the `</tr>` tag and the `<tr>` tag

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you even try to do this yourself?

Comment: Please be sure if you go the regex route you are careful to avoid `tr` tags in `CDATA` sections and comments, that you watch for attributes in the `tr` start tags, etc. etc.  And unless this is a one-time clean up you are doing, please do consider an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = subject.replace(/<\/tr>\s*<tr>/g, "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>");
```